# Selenium wait until expected conditions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to search for something, after clicking the search button, the button going into an loading animation. If there is a result, it goes to the next page, if there is no result, a yellow box appears. How can I write this line `new WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until`? I'm thinking until the title change or the yellow box appears. But I'm not sure how can I code that.

This is what I got so far

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(driver.getTitle().contains("Overview") || !driver.findElements(By
                    .xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/span"));
                    .isEmpty())
```

Comment: Add language tag. Looks like Java)

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public WebDriverWait waitSec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);
}

public WebElement clickableByXpath(String xpath, int sec) {
    WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
    return element;
}
  
public WebElement clickableById(String id, int sec) {
    WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(id)));
    return element;
}
  
public WebElement visibleById(String id, int sec) {
    WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
    return element;
}
  
public WebElement visibleByXpath(String xpath, int sec) {
    WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
    return element;
}


// custom ExpectedCondition
public ExpectedCondition<Boolean> elementNotVisible(String xpath) {
    return ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
}
```

See https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html